# Force Facebook Like Box width

Tags: html, css, facebook

According to the Facebook newest change, [like box plugin is now depraced](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-box-for-pages) - so we need to use a [page plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) instead, which minimum width is set to the 280 px.

Along with those changes, CSS hacks like those won't work anymore:

```
.fb_iframe_widget>span { width: 260px !important; }
.fb_iframe_widget iframe { width: 260px !important; }
```

Thats because we can't access a document loaded by the iframe and set this div attribute:

[image]

Is there any other way to force a new page plugin width to be smaller than 280px?

Comment: What happens when you go on the `.fb_iframe_widget` istelf?

Comment: I know this is not the answer you are looking for, but I think you should reconsider doing this at all. The reason being that modifying Facebook's social plugins would be a violation of their Platform Policy, and you could also create a degraded user experience for some locales where the wording of the box's content actually takes up all 280px - which would then also be a violation of Facebook's Platform Policy